# D3 v4 how to synchronously iterate through data

Tags: javascript, dictionary, asynchronous, d3.js, callback

I have an array called `states` that is an array of arrays. Each array element has 2 items, a United States state name and its abbreviation:

```
states = [
  ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
  ['Alabama', 'AL'],
  ['Alaska', 'AK'],
  ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
  ['California', 'CA'],
  ...
  ]
```

I have a map called `statesData` with key = state abbreviation. I'm trying to use the `states` array to create a new map with the same values as `statesData`, but with the key equal to the state's full name:

```
function setStatesFullData(statesFullData, statesData) {
  statesData.each(function(key, value) {
    states.forEach(function(element) {
      if (key == element[1]) {
        statesFullData.set(element[0], value);
      }
    })
  })
  console.log(statesFullData.size());
  return statesFullData;
}


var statesFullData = d3.map();
statesFullData = setStatesFullData(statesFullData, statesData);
```

Output:

```
0
```

This is expected due to variable scoping and (I believe) that `map.each` and `array.forEach` are asynchronous functions.

I currently don't understand how I can around this: the data has to exist outside the `statesData.forEach` function to be used, and by then the data will not exist.

I think there's something about asynchronous development that I'm missing.

I can provide more info on request. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Full Demo (also below): https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/YzXNGyZ)

A step-by-step explanation is at the bottom of this answer

```js
const states = [
  ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
  ['Alabama', 'AL'],
  ['Alaska', 'AK'],
  ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
  ['California', 'CA']
];

const statesReversed = states.map((child, index) =>{
  return [...child.reverse()]
});

console.log(statesReversed);
const statesConversionObject = Object.fromEntries(statesReversed);
console.log(statesConversionObject);

const statesData = {
  'AZ': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AL': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AK': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AR': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'CA': ['Some', 'Data']
};

const statesDataModified = {};

for (let key in statesData){
  const newKey = statesConversionObject[key];
  statesDataModified[newKey] = statesData[key];
}

console.log(statesDataModified);
const statesFullData = d3.map(statesDataModified);
console.log(statesFullData);
```

[image]

[image]

Step by Step:

Original Data:

```
const states = [
  ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
  ['Alabama', 'AL'],
  ['Alaska', 'AK'],
  ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
  ['California', 'CA']
];

const statesData = {
  'AZ': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AL': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AK': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'AR': ['Some', 'Data'],
  'CA': ['Some', 'Data']
};
```

1. Reverse our array of arrays (might be called array of touples in other languages). We do the reversing by using `array.map()` to iterate over the outer array and `[...child.reverse()]` to reverse the inner array:

   ```
   const statesReversed = [
     ['AZ', 'Arizona',],
     ['AL', 'Alabama'],
     ['AK', 'Alaska'],
     ['AR', 'Arkansas'],
     ['CA', 'California']
   ];
   ```
2. Then we can take this and use it to create a javascript object (/hash table) 
   using `Object.fromEntries(statesReversed)` so that we can use this to essentially "lookup" abbreviations and return full names. We do this using:

   ```
   const statesConversionObject = Object.fromEntries(statesReversed);
   //which gives us:
   statesConversionObject = {
     AK: "Alaska",
     AL: "Alabama",
     AR: "Arkansas",
     AZ: "Arizona",
     CA: "California"
   }
   ```
3. This allows us to do this lookup like so:

   ```
   const statesDataModified = {};

   for (let key in statesData){
     const newKey = statesConversionObject[key];
     statesDataModified[newKey] = statesData[key];
   }
   ```
4. We get in return:

   ```
   statesDataModified = {
     'Arizona': ['Some', 'Data'],
     'Alabama': ['Some', 'Data'],
     'Alaska': ['Some', 'Data'],
     'Arkansas': ['Some', 'Data'],
     'California': ['Some', 'Data']
   };
   ```
5. Finally, convert to `d3.map()`:

   ```
   const statesFullData = d3.map(statesDataModified);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a new `Map` object used for mapping states' abbreviations to their full names by passing a new copy of your `states` array to the `Map` constructor having keys and values reversed:

```
const statesMap = new Map(states.map(([name, abbr]) => [abbr, name]));
```

This acts as helper to resolve states' names when subsequently creating the new `statesFullData` map from the `statesData` map:

```
const statesFullData = new Map(                    // Create new map (full names-to-data) from...
  Array.from(                                      // ...array...
    statesData,                                    // ...from previous map (abbr-to-data)...
    ([abbr, data]) => [statesMap.get(abbr), data]  // ...keys resolved to full name by abbreviation.
  )
);
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
const states = [
  ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
  ['Alabama', 'AL'],
  ['Alaska', 'AK'],
  ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
  ['California', 'CA'],
];

const statesData = new Map([
  ['AZ', "AZ data"],
  ['AL', "AL data"],
  ['AK', "AK data"],
  ['AR', "AR data"],
  ['CA', "CA data"],
]);

const statesMap = new Map(states.map(([name, abbr]) => [abbr, name]));

const statesFullData = new Map(
  Array.from(
    statesData,
    ([abbr, data]) => [statesMap.get(abbr), data]
  )
);

console.log(...statesFullData);
```